# html onchange textarea only call the function() once. when change of text, the image doesnt change

Tags: javascript, html

As mentioned above in the title I cannot get the onchange to call myfunction() everytime users type in the textarea, it supposed to change the image everytime it type

Anyone can please help on that, I am a newbie to html and javascript. I just need the image to change to what people have typed in the text area.

```
 <!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough" lang="us">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>〈Magnetic〉writesomething</title>
<link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>

body{
    font: 62.5% "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
    margin: 50px;
}
html, body {
height: 100%;
}

html {
display: table;
margin: auto;
}

body {
display: table-cell;
        padding: .8em 2em .8em 20px;

}
.image { 
   position: relative; 
   width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
}

h2 {
position: relative;
top: 80px;
left: 360px;
width: 200px;
height: 90px;
color:#FFFFFF;
font-size:36px;
margin: 0 auto;

}
h4 {

width: 600px;


}

img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
z-index:-1;
}

div.relative {
position: relative;
left: 20px;
border: 3px solid #8AC007;
}

#container {
width:600px;
height:350px;

 position: relative;
}
#image {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width:100%;
height: auto;
}
#text {
 z-index: 100;
 position: absolute;
 color: white;
 font-size: 22px;
 font-weight: bold;
 left: 250px;
 top: 80px;
}

</style>


</head>

<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<div class="container">

    <h1 class="container">〈Magnetic〉writesomething</h1>

    <div style="display: block;">
    <div id="imgDiv" class="image">

 <img src="http://game.magnetic.hk/image.php?text=writesomething
  " />
  <p id="display"></p>
  </div>


</div>

    <p>Write something：</p>
<form action="image.php" method="post" name="myform">

      <textarea style="width:600px;" name="text" id="inputtext"     onChange="myFunction()" placeholder="上限為16個字">中秋祝你乜乜乜</textarea></br>    </br>


</form>



</div>

<script src="jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
      function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("inputtext").value;
document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = x;

 document.getElementById('imgDiv').innerHTML='<img src=\'http://game.magnetic.hk/image.php?text='+ document.getElementById("display").innerHTML +'\'>'

}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try using `onInput` instead of `onChange`

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code line with this one. And check the last element after closing image tag. The same paragraph should be there.

```
document.getElementById('imgDiv').innerHTML = '<img src=\'http://game.magnetic.hk/image.php?text=' + document.getElementById("display").innerHTML + '\'><p id="display"></p>'
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `document.getElementById('imgDiv').innerHTML` you remove the `<p id="display"></p>`.

If you replace

```
document.getElementById('imgDiv').innerHTML='<img src=\'http://game.magnetic.hk/image.php?text='+ document.getElementById("display").innerHTML +'\'>'
```

by:

```
document.getElementById('imgDiv').innerHTML='<img src=\'http://game.magnetic.hk/image.php?text='+ document.getElementById("display").innerHTML +'\'><p id="display"></p>'
```

It should work.
You can try it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/x9rrovyr/).

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned every time a user types and I see that you are using jQuery.

Try like this.

--Update--

Didn't realize the text not appearing.

```
$("#inputtext").on("keydown", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    var x = $(this).val();
    console.log(x);
    $("#display").text(x);

    $('#imgDiv > img').attr('src', 'http://game.magnetic.hk/image.php?text=' + x);

}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devkickstart/nn1eqkw3/2/)

--EDIT--

[image: Screen shot of the result]

Comment: Your fiddle still seems broken, I cannot enter more than one character in the textarea. `myFunction` is called only once.

Comment: The "many many characters....." that you have entered in the textarea is not showing up on the image where the guy is holding the purple card..

Answer (score 0):

@Elie Gnrd's answer explains why your code is broken.

Since you are using jQuery put its selectors and binding to use.

Modify your script to this,

```
$('#inputtext').on('input', function () {
    var x = $("#inputtext").val();
    $("#display").html(x);
    $('#imgDiv').html('<img src=\'http://game.magnetic.hk/image.php?text=' + x + '\'>');
});
```

And, remove the onChange attribute from textarea

Checkout the working fiddle here.. https://jsfiddle.net/sachin_puthran/h2c06fjx/